# Cannot create PV on /dev/dm-NN (/dev/dm-N works)

Tags: linux, storage, lvm, device-mapper

I'm unable to create PVs on Multipath-Volumes that are available at
/dev/dm-NN where N~[0-9] but I can create them on single digit devices
like `/dev/dm-9`:

```
# pvcreate /dev/dm-6
  Physical volume "/dev/dm-6" successfully created.

# pvcreate /dev/dm-16
  Device /dev/dm-16 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

My Version of LVM is 2.02.168 from Debian 9.
The filter ist set to a permissive value:

```
  filter = [ "a|.*|" ]
  global_filter = [ "a|.*|" ]
```

Any ideas why two or more digits in the device path can cause it to be
filtered by pvcreate?

Comment: this is no related to your problem, but for multipath lun you need to use device under /dev/mapper/mpaX, use multipath -ll

Comment: That's where I actually started out, by using `/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-mpath-xyz` but those are just symlinks to /dev/dm-NN and the longer path works as long as it points to a single digit like /dev/dm-6.

Comment: can you add the output of `parted /dev/dm-16 print` and `multipath -l  mpaX`

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. Somehow those disks with two digits in their name had a GPT on them, while those with a single digit had not. I wiped all disks like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/dm-xx bs=1M count=100
```

After that I was able to create PVs on all of them. I'm not able to tell where those GPTs came from.